# Code not returning line if there is no newline character

Tags: c, getline, file-descriptor

I started coding in C a few months ago. I wrote this code to return each line from a file. It has to work with any buffer size, which right now it does, and it should return each line present in the file. However if I don't have a newline character at the end of my line, my code does not return anything.

So far I believe the issue is in my `get_next_line` function. I can see that I can get the line without the newline character into the line variable, as well as the stash variable. However, after the code cleans the stash, I believe it enters the `if` condition `(stash[0] == '\0')`, therefore ending my program before returning my line which is in my line variable. I added this condition as a way to terminate my `main` `while` loop, so if I remove it the code gets stuck on an infinite loop. I have tried other approaches and I managed to get all lines but then it only worked with buffer sizes greater than the size of my file, I did this by changing the `i` variable to be equal to `find_nl(line) + (line[0] != '\0');`. In this scenario, for smaller buffers I would get the lines but they would be "broken".

I'm at the very beginning of learning C so I would be grateful for any inputs to improve this code. **Thank you** in advance.

**Here is the program:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int find_nl(char *stash);
char *get_line(char *stash, char *line);
void ft_clean(char *stash);

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char     stash[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char            *line;
    int         n;
    int         i;

    if (fd < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    line = NULL;
    while (!i)
    {
        if (!stash[0])
            n = read(fd, stash, BUFFER_SIZE);   
        if (n == -1)
            return (NULL);
        line = get_line(stash, line);
        i = find_nl(stash) + (line == NULL);
        if (stash[0] == '\0')
            return (NULL);
        ft_clean(stash);
    }
    return (line);
}

int find_nl(char *stash)
{
    size_t      i;

    if (stash == NULL)
        return (0);
    i = 0;
    while (stash[i])
    {
        if (stash[i] == '\n')
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

char    *get_line(char *stash, char *line)
{
    size_t  len;
    size_t  i;
    size_t  j;
    char    *nline;

    len = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (stash[len] && stash[len] != '\n')
        len++;
    if (line == NULL)
        i = 0;
    else
        while (line[i])
            i++;
    nline = (char *)malloc((len + i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (nline == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (line && line[j])
    {
        nline[j] = line[j];
        j++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        nline[j] = stash[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    nline[j] = '\0';
    return (nline);
}

void    ft_clean(char *stash)
{
    size_t  stash_len;
    size_t  len;
    size_t  i;

    len = 0;
    stash_len = 0;
    i = 0;
    if (stash == NULL)
        return ;
    while (stash[len])
    {
        if (stash[len] == '\n')
        {
            len++;
            break ;
        }
        len++;
    }
    while (stash[stash_len] != '\0')
        stash_len++;
    while (i < stash_len - len + 1)
    {
        stash[i] = stash[i + len];
        i++;
    }
    stash[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char *line;
    while ((line = get_next_line(0)) != NULL) {
        printf("[%s]\n", line);
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works if called as follows:

```bash
printf 'abc\n' | ./a
```

But the following doesn't output anything:

```bash
printf 'abc' | ./a
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i edited the post to add the includes

Comment: @TomKarzes i am obligated by the project to use only the low level system calls

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for the input i initialized the variable

Comment: [On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sWExK5TY9) No further time.

Comment: Note that compiling with `-fsanitize=address` shows a memory leak. Not the problem you asked about, but it's something you should look into.

Comment: You don't use the result of `read` except to check if `read` resulted in an error. There's definitely a bug there.

Comment: `read()` does not add a `'\0'` byte after the end. You have to make sure it is there or use some other method to check for it.

Comment: OT: Please use the same indentation style everywhere (your `main` has a different indentation style than the rest). Please make sure the example is compilable.

Comment: Note that the interface to `get_next_line` makes no sense. Imagine if you called it to read from two different files. It would use the same buffer for both. The buffer should be provided as an argument, or the `fd` should also be global.

Comment: @CVB `malloc()` and `free()` may call `mmap()` (assuming you are on a unix-like system, like Linux or Mac OS X).

Comment: Re "*`read()` does not add a `'\0'` byte after the end*", yeah, that's why I mentioned that one needs to use the value returned by `read`.

Comment: Is it a requirement to return lines of arbitrary length as a C-String? If so, you would have to use `mmap()` and family (if you want to avoid `malloc()`, like you mentioned). If not, it can be made simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but i think there is a better approach. Your current code is hard to understand, not very modular and buggy.

You are using `malloc()` and `free()` in your code, normally there is nothing wrong with that, but since you have the requirement of

> i am obligated by the project to use only the low level system calls

You can't use them.

Instead of using `static` variables inside the function (`get_next_line()` in your case for `stash` and potentially more since that would be required for a better implementation), i would suggest using a `struct` and passing the pointer to that `struct` when calling this functions. This would also allow you to use this functions for more than a single file at (quasi) the same time.

Something like this:

```
struct File_T
{
  int fd;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  size_t currentLineEnd; //position of the first char after the current line
  size_t validChars;
};

void file_init(struct File_T *file, int fd);
const char *file_getNextLine(struct File_T *file);


void file_init(struct File_T *file, int fd)
{
    file->fd=fd;
    file->currentLineEnd=0; 
    file->validChars=0;
}
```

When you `read()` from a file, you may receive `'\0'` bytes but `read()` itself does not add a `'\0'` at the end, i.e. `read()` does not fill a string but a buffer that can contain any data. You need to use the return value of `read()` to check how many characters where read. I suggest, you read to the `buffer` after the last valid character (which was set from the last time you `read()` or at 0) and you can at the amount of read characters to `validChars`. Also note that `read()` returns a `ssize_t` type and not `int`.

```
ssize_t n = read(file->fd,&file->buffer[file->validChars],BUFFER_SIZE-file->validChars-1); //-1 so we can always add a '\0'
if( n<0 )
  { /*do some error handling here*/ }
file->validChars+=n;
```

To avoid `malloc()` you can search for `'\n'` in the `buffer` (till you reach `validChars`, after that you either have to read more or have to decide that there is no space left in the buffer or you read the last line, then you have to use the next char after the `validChars` position) and replace it with a `'\0'`, set `currentLineEnd` to 1 character after that and return a pointer to the start. When `file_getNextLine()` is called next time, move everything valid from `currentLineEnd` till `validChars` to the beginning  (with `memmove()` or your own implementation of it) and repeat the process.

### Edit:

If you need to handle lines of arbitrary length, without setting `BUFFER_SIZE` so large, you could allocate new memory for the string to store and don't use `currentLineEnd`. Since you don't want to use `malloc()`, you can reserve a buffer with `mmap()`. Like this:

```
char *buffer=mmap(NULL,newBufferSize,PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
```

Don't forget to `munmap()` it later.

Comment: @ikegami But the allocated buffer and the resulting string is not longer (except maybe +1 or so, since he uses +1 for the size, i am not sure). He has to use `mmap()` and family when he wants to use dynamic memory when he wants to use only the low level system calls.

Comment: @ikegami From where did you get that? I didn't read that requirement. And this is impossible, at least in the way he uses the line (as a single string). To store a C-string of 1000 bytes you need a buffer of at least 1001 bytes.

Comment: @ikegami The OP has the requirement to only use low level system calls. That means no `malloc()`, `calloc()` nor `free()`. He can use `mmap()` (supposed he uses a unix-like system), but since he didn't, i also didn't include it.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, if that is the goal of the OP, i could add, but for that he would have to answer the comment (which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be rather complicated. Here's my attempt at solving the problem:

`read_line.h`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

#define GET_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
   int fd;
   int error;
   int eof;
   size_t in_buf;
   char buffer[ GET_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE ];
} ReadLineData;

ReadLineData *ReadLine_new( int fd );
void ReadLine_init( ReadLineData *data, int fd );
void ReadLine_destroy( ReadLineData *data );
void ReadLine_free( ReadLineData *data );

// Returns -1 on error.    *line_ptr is set to NULL.  errno is set.
// Returns  0 on EOF.      *line_ptr is set to NULL.
// Returns +1 on success.  *line_ptr is set to a string to free.
int ReadLine_read_line( ReadLineData *data, char **line_ptr );
```

`read_line.c`:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "read_line.h"

void ReadLine_init( ReadLineData *data, int fd ) {
   data->fd     = fd;
   data->error  = 0;
   data->eof    = 0;
   data->in_buf = 0;
}

// Returns NULL on error.  errno is set.
ReadLineData *ReadLine_new( int fd ) {
   ReadLineData *data = malloc( sizeof( ReadLineData ) );
   if ( data )
      ReadLine_init( data, fd );

   return data;
}

void ReadLine_destroy( ReadLineData *data ) {
   (void)data;  // Nothing to do.
}

void ReadLine_free( ReadLineData *data ) {
   ReadLine_destroy( data );
   free( data );
}

static char *find_lf( ReadLineData *data ) {
   char *p = data->buffer;
   for ( size_t n = data->in_buf; n--; ++p ) {
      if ( *p == '\n' ) {
         return p;
      }
   }

   return NULL;
}

// Returns false on error.  errno is set.
// Returns true on success.
static bool safe_size_add( size_t *acc_ptr, size_t to_add ) {
   if ( to_add > SIZE_MAX - *acc_ptr ) {
      errno = ENOMEM;
      return false;
   }

   return true;
} 

// Returns false on error.  errno is set.
// Returns true on success.
static bool move_to_line(
   ReadLineData *data,
   char **line_ptr,        // in-out. Set to NULL on error.
   size_t *line_len_ptr,   // in-out.
   size_t n
) {
   char *line      = *line_ptr;
   size_t line_len = *line_len_ptr;

   // Calculate new line size.
   // Protect against overflow.
   size_t new_line_len_p1 = line_len;
   if ( !safe_size_add( &new_line_len_p1, n ) )
      goto ERROR;
   if ( !safe_size_add( &new_line_len_p1, 1 ) )
      goto ERROR;

   // Enlarge the buffer.
   char *new_line = realloc( line, new_line_len_p1 );
   if ( !new_line )
      goto ERROR;

   line = new_line;

   // Copy from the buffer.
   memmove( line + line_len , data->buffer, n );
   line_len += n;
   line[ line_len ] = 0;

   // Remove from the buffer.
   data->in_buf -= n;
   memcpy( data->buffer, data->buffer + n, data->in_buf );

   *line_ptr     = line;
   *line_len_ptr = line_len;
   return true;

ERROR:
   free( line );
   *line_ptr = NULL;
   return false;
}

// Returns -1 on error.    *line_ptr is set to NULL.  errno is set.
// Returns  0 on EOF.      *line_ptr is set to NULL.
// Returns +1 on success.  *line_ptr is set to a string to free.
int ReadLine_get_line( ReadLineData *data, char **line_ptr ) {
   *line_ptr = NULL;
   size_t line_len = 0;

   if ( data->eof )
      return 0;

   while ( 1 ) {
      if ( data->in_buf ) {
         char *lf = find_lf( data );
         if ( lf )
            return move_to_line( data, line_ptr, &line_len, lf - data->buffer + 1 ) ? +1 : -1;

         // We didn't find a LF, so the whole buffer is part of the line.
         if ( !move_to_line( data, line_ptr, &line_len, data->in_buf ) )
            return -1;
      }

      // We need to read more.
      ssize_t bytes_read = read( data->fd, data->buffer, GET_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE );
      if ( bytes_read < 0 ) {
         data->eof   = 1;
         data->error = 1;
         free( *line_ptr );
         *line_ptr = NULL;
         return -1;
      }

      if ( bytes_read == 0 ) {
         data->eof = 1;
         return line_len ? +1 : 0;
      }

      data->in_buf = bytes_read;
   }
}
```

Program:

```c
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "read_line.h"

int main( void ) {
   ReadLineData data;
   ReadLine_init( &data, 0 );

   while ( 1 ) {
      char *line;
      int rv = ReadLine_read_line( &data, &line );
      if ( rv < 0 )
         err( EXIT_FAILURE, "read_line" );
      if ( rv == 0 )
         break;

      printf( "[%s]\n", line );
      free( line );      
   }

   ReadLine_destroy( &data );
}
```

It uses `memcpy`, `memmove` and `realloc`. If you want to avoids those, the first two are easy to re-implement yourself. `realloc` would be trickier to re-implement, and would require something like `mmap`. This is an exercise left to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this function would help. It's called fgets and you can use it instead of read function.If you can't use just copy the idea behind it.

[Function Implementation](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/fgets.c)

[Function Documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fgets.html)

Definition: char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a <newline> is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte. Upon successful completion, fgets() shall return s. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, fgets() shall return a null pointer.

Combine it with this:

```
int get_cleaned_line(char str[], int maxlen)  //I never used read, idk fd  what it is
{             //you can use BUFFER_SIZE instead of maxlen
int len = -1;

    if (fgets(str, maxlen, stdin) != NULL)  //I think stdin it's like fd=0(input from keyboard)
    {               //whatever use the proper input file
    len = 0;
    while(str[len] != '\0')
        len++;
        if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') 
        {
            str[len-1] = '\0';
            len--;
        }

return len; //can be useful
}
```

I just learned C one year ago and i really hate strings, Hope this helps.

Comment: If `fread` isn't allowed, then neither is `fgets`! Also, your solution is unable to read lines that are longer than `maxlen` whereas the OP specifically handled that.

Comment: @ikegami i didn't read any of this restrictions from the OP. Only now i checked, he said this things in the comments and not inside question. but he can still take inspiration from this answer, there is no need to downvote. i just wanted to help and he requested for any input and not full solution.

Comment: Still, it doesn't answer the question. It should be fixed or deleted. (For two reasons. You didn't even address one of them.)

Comment: @ikegami Giving your implemetation instead of letting him write his own idea of the code its not an answer as well.You are using structs when it's clear he's not using it for the same reason he can't use high level functions. he is at beginning.

Comment: That makes so sense.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).